# Avoiding congestion in large scale contracts

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

I have a contract that will implement a client/server-like functionality through the use of of events (peers have event listeners and make method calls depending on the events they are listening to).

If each peer listens to a an event bound to a method that all remaining peers call then the respective peer will get flooded with **log** data. I was thinking about writing multiple method with different names but same argument list and functionality and use a scheduler to select one based on a seed provided by the caller. Are there any large scale contracts with thousands of interacting peers? If yes, how is complexity managed?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a problem? Emitting logs is expensive, listening to logs is practically free. So if there is a bottleneck it should be the contract, not the peers.

Comment: Adding to @ComandanteCheths comment, plus these are there by design.

Comment: I know that listening to logs is not costly but I was asking in the case of a scenario that each client is notified by the remaining peers in the network given that each peers calls a contract method meant to be called by clients thus causing broadcasts of events to all peers listening to an event bound to that method.